# Movilizer - Masterdata pool id as integer across participant/devices

Tags: mobile, movilizer

A masterdata descriptor like this one: `$masterdata:"pool_name"` is converted in the Movilizer client to an integer number like 113.

We are building a logic that sends back to the backend the poolid (113) and the key modified (key="key1") in a DataContainer.

The DataContainer key is formed like this: "poolid$$key", my question is:

Is the poolid integer number the same accross participant/devices?? (Always 113), or is it random depending on the client?

I need to know this to send some string with the poolname instead of the poolid for this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have to guess I'd say the poolID mapping is the same over all participants/devices and depends on the order of pools as they are created in a systemID. Probably the first pool that is created in the sysID gets the mapping 0 or 1 ... and so on. But this is just a wild guess and I am not sure if your approach is advisable at all. In the end it could all rely on an unsorted data structure and might change the ordering of the id's in unexpected ways based on that.

Comment: Thanks for you answer André, then we'll have to send a string descriptor for the pool, but that is understandable.